# Print_r parts of a path

Tags: php

Is it possible to print_r only som parts of the path ?
Ex only print_r:  folder3

```
   $str = $filename;
$arr = array_filter(explode('/',$str));
$out = array('/'.implode('/',$arr).'/');
while((array_pop($arr) and !empty($arr))){
    $out[] = '/'.implode('/',$arr).'/';
};
print_r($out);
```

result of print_r:

```
[0] => /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/folder6
    [1] => /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/
    [2] => /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/
    [3] => /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/
    [4] => /home/folder1/folder2/
    [5] => /home/folder1/
[6] => /home/
```

Comment: `echo $out[3];` perhaps - your question isnt very clear

Comment: if i do so the print_r is : [3] => /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/

Comment: i want it to print_r folder clean name not parts of whole path. If i echo $[3] i want the output to be [3] => folder3

Comment: Still not really clear what you want to do. Is the answer by @Shim-Sao sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not this :

```
$str = $filename;
$num = 3;

$arr = explode('/',$str);
echo $arr[$num];
```